# Obtaining xts object from R function that is based on matrix operations

Tags: r, matrix, xts, performanceanalytics

I have the following R function that calculates EWMA volatility for given securities:

```
EWMAvol = function(returns, lambda, rollwindow){
  EWMA.mat = matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(returns), ncol = ncol(returns))
  for (k in 1 : ncol(returns)){  
    for (j in rollwindow : nrow(returns)){
      td = returns
      data = as.matrix(td[(j - rollwindow + 1) : j, k])
      ewmaVar.mat = matrix()
      ewmaVar.mat[1] = 0
      for (i in 2 : rollwindow){
        ewmaVar.mat[i] = lambda * ewmaVar.mat[i-1]+ (1 - lambda) * data[i]^2
      }
      EWMA.mat[j, k] = sqrt(ewmaVar.mat[length(ewmaVar.mat)])
    }
  }
  return(EWMA.mat)
}
```

The data that this function relies on is:

```
> class(rets)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

which is coming from the `Return.calculate()` function from `PerformanceAnalytics` package.

The output that I currently get is:

```
> class(EWMAvol)
[1] "matrix"
```

Is it possible to return a `xts` or `zoo` object/data from my code?
Also, I would like to keep the column names. How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Return.calculate` function returns an `xts`, so you can use the `index` of that to convert your final return value to an `xts`.

I'd do it by substituting the last line of your function

```
return(EWMA.mat)
```

with the following:

```
EWMA.xts = xts::xts(EWMA.mat, order.by = zoo::index(returns))
colnames(EWMA.xts) = colnames(returns) # to preserve column names
return(EWMA.xts)
```

Comment: Thank you, +1. Now a minor issue -- how do I keep the column names?

Comment: Great! Been following your activity here since you are a Quant. Just curious, have you finished developing your factor models?

Comment: @AK88 More or less. I'm thinking about portfolio optimisation, now.